# Programmatically remove specific class name from HTML element

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In C# ASP.NET I am adding a class to an `<input>` using:

```
myInput.Attributes.Add("class","myClass");
```

At some point I would like to remove the added class (not all classes). Is there an equivalent along the lines of:

```
myInput.Attributes.Remove("class","myClass");
```

`.Remove()` seems to only accept a key (no pair value). Thank you!

Comment: When do you need to remove the CSS class? If the `<input>` element has no `runat="server"` then any attribute you added from code-behind will not be persisted between postbacks, anyway.

Comment: Good call, I didn't even bother to think about that. Thanks for helping me realize I don't have to worry about removing it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing built in to manage multiple values in the attribute.

You will have to parse the list, remove the class name and update the attribute.

Something like (untested):

```
var classes = myInput.Attributes["class"].Split(' ');

var updated = classes.Where(x => x != "classtoremove").ToArray();

myInput.Attributes["class"] = string.Join(" ", updated);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I see what you're going for but the .Where doesn't seem to be valid. If you don't mind correcting the syntax (or help me understand on how to implement that) I'll mark it as correct. It's much more efficient than how I would implement looping through the array.

Comment: @Jesse - The `Where` is fine, if you have a `using System.Linq;` statement.

Comment: I only seem to be able to use `Where` on `List`s and not `Array`s.

Comment: @Jesse - OK. Just add a `.ToList()` after the `Split(' ')`.

Comment: I have two classes in my label but I want to remove only one... same process? Thanks.

Comment: @Search - you just make sure the value is the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

I got inspired by Odeds post and created these two extension methods for you to elaborate with;

```
public static void AddCssClass(this WebControl control, params string[] args)
{
    List<string> classes = control.CssClass.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList<string>();
    List<string> classesToAdd = args.Where(x => !classes.Contains(x)).ToList<string>();
    classes.AddRange(classesToAdd);
    control.CssClass = String.Join(" ", classes);
}
public static void RemoveCssClass(this WebControl control, params string[] args)
{
    List<string> classes = control.CssClass.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList<string>();
    classes = classes.Where(x => !args.Contains(x)).ToList<string>();
    control.CssClass = String.Join(" ", classes);
}
```

The methods are simply used to add or remove CSS classes from [WebControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx) (from where [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx)s, [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx)s, [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx)s etc. all inherits) like `myButton.AddCssClass("class1", "class2");` or `myButton.RemoveCssClass("class2");`.

It might very well be a bit overhead but managing the [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) property can also be a bit of a hassle as you´re forced to handle the whitespaces on your own.

How many times haven´t you seen this one, for example?

```
string myCssClass = "class1";
myButton.CssClass += " " + myCssClass;
```

Please feel free to improve the methods! :)